# Spring data jpa. Postgres. UUID. Call stored procedure with uuid[] parameter

Tags: spring, postgresql, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, uuid

Need an example how to call stored procedure which takes postgres uuid[] array as parameter with spring data jpa. Always getting exception that function does not exist with parameter bytea.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question - if you have a field

```
    private UUID myfield;
```

in your @Entity, you can have a method

```
    findByMyfield(UUID myfield);
```

in your JpaRepository.

A proper mapping is another thing (as you have an exception) - you can check https://bootfy.io if it can give you a running schema.